# changing background-color of textbox

Tags: angular

I am trying to change the background color of a textbox when someone enters the color in the textbox in angular 4. But its not working. I am using Visual Studio Code. Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" ngModel="myColor" ng-style="{background-color: myColor}">
```

Comment: [ngStyle]="{background-color: myColor}" is the Angular (2+) method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myColor" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': myColor}">
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct syntax to use ngClass, try the following code:

```
<input type="text" ngModel="myColor"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': myColor}">
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular syntax should be **`[(ngModel)`**] and **`[ngStyle]`**,

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myColor" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': myColor}">
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/AW424shgYyE9dLsQPN0E?p=preview)**